# SQL Query - max(count()) - possible without CTE?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

*I'm studying for my Database Systems exam at the moment, having some trouble with an exercise creating a query.*

**I have four tables:**

1. A **referent**-table with personal data of referents,
2. A **course**-table with course data (with the responsible referent as foreign key),
3. A **workshop**-table with workshop data (with the corresponding course as foreign key),
4. A **booking**-table which manages bookings (with the corresponding workshop which has been booked as a foreign key)

My exercise is to find out **how much money** a referent earns (there's a **price**-column in workshop)

It's not very difficult to list how much money he earns **per** workshop; I created this query to show me:

```sql
SELECT  r.referentid,
    r.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM g22_courses c WHERE c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)*c.price AS income
FROM referent r
LEFT JOIN g22_courses c ON (c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)
LEFT JOIN g22_workshop w ON (w.courseid = c.id)
LEFT JOIN g22_booking b ON (b.workshopid = w.id)
GROUP BY r.referentid, c.responsiblerefid
```

This returns this:

```
2;"Anna";0.60
4;"Ahmed";3.5
1;"Hans";
2;"Anna";13.20
3;"Wolfgang";
```

**As you can see, it works fine.**

I now have **two** rows for Anna (because she is responsible for **two** courses..) and want to  have **one** row with the sum of both tables.

Unfortunately, the only way to do this (as I found out) is with a **Common Table Expression** (CTE) - with a CTE it works:

```sql
WITH incomepercourse AS (
    SELECT  r.referentid,
        r.name,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM g22_courses c WHERE c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)*c.price AS income
    FROM referent r
    LEFT JOIN g22_courses c ON (c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)
    LEFT JOIN g22_workshop w ON (w.courseid = c.id)
    LEFT JOIN g22_booking b ON (b.workshopid = w.id)
    GROUP BY r.referentid, c.responsiblerefid
)

SELECT  referentid, name, SUM(income) FROM incomepercourse GROUP BY referentid, name
```

this returns:

```
3;"Wolfgang";
4;"Ahmed";3.50
2;"Anna";13.80
1;"Hans";
```

### Is there any way to avoid a CTE?

My professor didn't talk about CTE, and it also isn't in his lecture notes - so there **has** to be some other, simpler way.

Is there anyone out there who knows a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: PostgreSQL, I used the wrong tag :)

Comment: I only had a quick look, but isn't that simply: `sum(c.price)`? Due to the joins the price will be repeated for every booking. So the total income is the sum of all price rows.

Comment: Do you have the right columns in your group by statement? If you get rid of c.responsiblerefid and replace it with r.name I think it should work...

Comment: Gnaaah... a_horse_with_no_name, you're right :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the CTE part and query as shown below.

```
SELECT  tbl1.referentid, tbl1.name, SUM(tbl1.income) FROM (
    SELECT  r.referentid,
            r.name,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM g22_courses c WHERE c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)*c.Preis AS income
        FROM referent r
        LEFT JOIN g22_courses c ON (c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)
        LEFT JOIN g22_workshop w ON (w.courseid = c.id)
        LEFT JOIN g22_booking b ON (b.workshopid = w.id)
        GROUP BY r.referentid, c.responsiblerefid)tbl1      
GROUP BY tbl1.referentid, tbl1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to join the workshop and booking table if you do not use it.
If the price is in the course table as shown in your first request I think what you are asking for is answered by this request:

```
SELECT referent.referentid, referent.name, sum(price) 
FROM referent LEFT JOIN g22_courses ON g22_courses.responsiblerefid=referent.id
GROUP BY referent.referentid, referent.name
```

If the price is in the workshop table, just add a join to this table.

Answer (score 0):

### Okay, I solved it.

It was a problem with my understanding of the problem after all... ._.

I know managed to make a query like *a_horse_with_no_name* said in his comment:

```sql
SELECT  r.referentid,
    r.name,
    SUM(c.price) AS income
FROM referent r
LEFT JOIN g22_courses c ON (c.responsiblerefid = r.referentid)
LEFT JOIN g22_workshop w ON (w.courseid = c.id)
LEFT JOIN g22_booking b ON (b.workshopid = w.id)
GROUP BY r.referentid
ORDER BY r.referentid
```

This solves my problem perfectly, returning the right values.

**Thank you!**